# GGplot second y axis without the transformation of y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

Does any one know how do you apply this

```
set.seed(101)
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)
## second data set on a very different scale
z <- runif(10, min=1000, max=10000) 
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.3)  # Leave space for z axis
plot(x, y) # first plot
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, z, type = "l", axes = FALSE, bty = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(side=4, at = pretty(range(z)))
mtext("z", side=4, line=3)
```

but using ggplot.

In ggplot you can only create sec.axis() or dup.axis() using a transformation of y axis. What about a whole new independent y axis which will be applied only for z variable and the simple y axis to be applied for the y variable.

Comment: How is your `axis(.)` any different than doing the one additional step of determining the relationship between `y` and `z`? I don't disagree that sometimes this can be a chore, but ... there are many ways to do this incorrectly that the programmers chose to put the complete onus on the user.

Answer (score 3):

`ggplot2::sec_axis` provides only one mechanism for providing a second axis, and it took a lot of convincing to get that into the codebase. You are responsible for coming up with the transformation. This transform must be linear in some way, so if either axis needs to be non-linear (e.g., exponential, logarithmic, etc), then your expert math skills will be put to the test.

If you can use `scales`, then this process becomes *trivial*:

```r
dat <- data.frame(x, y, z)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(
    aes(y = zmod),
    data = ~ transform(., zmod = scales::rescale(z, range(y), range(z)))
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ scales::rescale(., range(dat$z), range(dat$y)),
                        breaks = c(2000,4000,6000,8000))
  )
```

[image: side by side of base and ggplot2 graphics]

Unless I've missed something (I just checked `ggplot2-3.3.5`'s NEWS.md file), this has not changed.